# How do I close a previously opened layout?

Tags: java, android

Im needing to know how to destroy previous class, when I open a new class so I dont have a ton of open classes to have to hit the 'back' button through to get back to 1st main class.

I know the layout code within the onCreate is typically this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.page);
```

i was thinking like `super.destroy();`

So when I use an intent to launch another class, I want the inital class to not leave behind open window/ContentView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By class, you mean another activity?

You can call finish(); after you have started the intent;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Android also takes care of these things himself. If memory is needed, the Dalvik virtual machine will close low priority activities that are running.

Comment: any reason i get 2 layouts opened when using this intent?

Comment: What do you mean with two layouts opened? My example was just to show that you can call finish after you launched the other activity. If the launching works properly in your application, I'd use that code and then just call finish after you start another activity.

Comment: Yah its weird.. if I add finish() to the intent like u suggest; then it closes the screen but open 2 new layouts, if I remove intent and leave finish() then it exits program, not sure why i get 2 layouts yet.. ALSO, is it possible to go back to one thats open with intent?

Comment: Are you replacing activity1 in my code by the the name of the activity you're working in at that moment and activity2 by the activity you want to go to? To go back: If you don't call finish() when you go to another activity and in that activity you launch that first activity again with an intent, it will go back to that activity as it was (if it's not closed by the Dalvik Virtual Machine to clean up memory, small chance).

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy is called automatically when the Activity is shut down. To remove your previos layout you can just call the method finish() or System.exit(0);